# Vue - access prop in component's mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I don't seem to be able to access a prop in `mounted` function.

This is how I render it:

```
{{landing}}
<vue-date-selector-comp v-bind:publishedat="landing.published_at" v-bind:cr="landing.created"></vue-date-selector-comp>
```

Here's my component code:

```
vue.component('vue-date-selector-comp', {
    props: ['publishedat', 'cr'],
    template: '<div class="vue-date-selector-comp-cont">{{cr}}</div>',
    mounted: function() {

        console.log('publishedat1',  this.publishedat);
        console.log('created2',  this.cr);

        this.$nextTick(function () {
            console.log('publishedat',  this.publishedat);
            console.log('created',  this.cr);
        });
    }
});
```

I only see `undefined` in the console... why? When I do {{landing}} before the component render -> I can see data is there. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: ahh nvm guys - landing is populated via ajax so there is my problem.

Comment: Is the `landing` var being updated / populated via an ajax or async call?

Comment: Do both the `landing.created` and `landing.published_at` properties exist?

Comment: @BrianGlaz ahh you're absolutely right- it  is async - so there is my problem

Comment: @Dannyboy Not sure if you have tried this, but you can try initializing those object props to empty values so that Vue knows about them. `landing: {'published_at': '', 'created': ''}` in the parent component.